# Training neural network for function approximation

Tags: c, neural-network, fann

I've got absolutely no experience with neural networks and for now I'm just playing with FANN library to learn them. So the objective is to train the network to approximate the sine function. For that I'm using 3 layer NN  1 input, 3 hidden and 1 output neuron. the code is

```
const unsigned int num_input = 1;
const unsigned int num_output = 1;
const unsigned int num_layers = 3;
const unsigned int num_neurons_hidden = 3;

struct fann *ann;

ann = fann_create_standard(num_layers, num_input, num_neurons_hidden, num_output);

fann_set_activation_steepness_hidden(ann, 1);
fann_set_activation_steepness_output(ann, 1);

fann_set_activation_function_hidden(ann, FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC);
fann_set_activation_function_output(ann, FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC);

fann_set_train_stop_function(ann, FANN_STOPFUNC_BIT);
fann_set_bit_fail_limit(ann, 0.01f);

fann_set_training_algorithm(ann, FANN_TRAIN_RPROP);

fann_randomize_weights(ann, 0, 1);

for(int i=0; i<2; ++i) {
    for(float angle=0; angle<10; angle+=0.1) {
        float sin_anle = sinf(angle);
        fann_train(ann, &angle, &sin_anle);
    }
}

int k = 0;
for(float angle=0; angle<10; angle+=0.1) {
    float sin_anle = sinf(angle);
    float *o = fann_run(ann, &angle);
    printf("%d\t%f\t%f\t\n", k++, *o, sin_anle);
}

fann_destroy(ann);
```

However I've got results that has nothing to do with the real sine function. I suppose that there is some fundamental error in my network design.

Comment: I can't find the error at the moment. But I'm not a FANN expert. Have you tried to play around with the parameters? Optimization algorithm (RPROP), number of hidden units, training epochs, ... Actually 2 training epochs should not be sufficient. I tried to increase the number but this didnt give me better results.

Comment: @alfa yes i've tried lots of different parameters. I think the problem is that there is only 1 in and one output parameter.

Comment: You are right. I'll post an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You choose the optimization algorithm Resilient Backpropagation (Rprop) in this line:

```
fann_set_training_algorithm(ann, FANN_TRAIN_RPROP);
```

[Rprop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rprop) is a **batch update** algorithm. This means you have to present the whole training set for each update. The documentation for [fann_train](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_train-h.html#fann_train) says

> This training is always incremental training (see fann_train_enum), since only one pattern is presented.

So the appropriate optimization option would be `FANN_TRAIN_INCREMENTAL`. You have to use one of these methods for batch learning: `fann_train_on_data`, `fann_train_on_file` or `fann_train_epoch`.

What I noticed when I changed your code was:

- Your steepness is too high. I used the default value (0.5).
- You have too few training epochs. I use about 20,000.
- Your function is too complex for only 3 hidden neurons. It is not easy at all because it is a periodic function. So I changed the range of the sine function I approximated to [0,3] which is much simpler.
- The bit fail limit is too hard. :) I set it to `0.02f`.
- Rprop is not a very good training algorithm, they should implement something like Levenberg-Marquardt, which is much faster.

The solution I got is not perfect but it is at least approximately correct:

```
0       0.060097        0.000000
1       0.119042        0.099833
2       0.188885        0.198669
3       0.269719        0.295520
4       0.360318        0.389418
5       0.457665        0.479426
6       0.556852        0.564642
7       0.651718        0.644218
8       0.736260        0.717356
9       0.806266        0.783327
10      0.860266        0.841471
11      0.899340        0.891207
12      0.926082        0.932039
...
```

I used this modified code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <fann.h>
#include <floatfann.h>

int main()
{
  const unsigned int num_input = 1;
  const unsigned int num_output = 1;
  const unsigned int num_layers = 3;
  const unsigned int num_neurons_hidden = 2;

  const float angleRange = 3.0f;
  const float angleStep = 0.1;
  int instances = (int)(angleRange/angleStep);

  struct fann *ann;

  ann = fann_create_standard(num_layers, num_input, num_neurons_hidden, num_output);

  fann_set_activation_function_hidden(ann, FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC);
  fann_set_activation_function_output(ann, FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC);

  fann_set_train_stop_function(ann, FANN_STOPFUNC_BIT);
  fann_set_bit_fail_limit(ann, 0.02f);

  fann_set_training_algorithm(ann, FANN_TRAIN_INCREMENTAL);

  fann_randomize_weights(ann, 0, 1);

  fann_train_data *trainingSet;
  trainingSet = fann_create_train(instances, 1, 1); // instances, input dimension, output dimension
  float angle=0;
  for(int instance=0; instance < instances; angle+=angleStep, instance++) {
      trainingSet->input[instance][0] = angle;
      trainingSet->output[instance][0] = sinf(angle);
  }

  fann_train_on_data(ann, trainingSet, 20000, 10, 1e-8f); // epochs, epochs between reports, desired error

  int k = 0;
  angle=0;
  for(int instance=0; instance < instances; angle+=angleStep, instance++) {
      float sin_angle = sinf(angle);
      float *o = fann_run(ann, &angle);
      printf("%d\t%f\t%f\t\n", k++, *o, sin_angle);
  }

  fann_destroy(ann);

  return 0;
}
```

Note that `fann_create_train` is available since FANN 2.2.0.